# Using simple averaging for reinforcment learning

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

I am currently reading [Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction](https://web.stanford.edu/class/psych209/Readings/SuttonBartoIPRLBook2ndEd.pdf) (RL:AI) and try to reproduce the first example with an n-armed bandit and simple reward averaging.

**Averaging**

```
new_estimate = current_estimate + 1.0 / step * (reward - current_estimate)
```

In order reproduce the graph from the PDF, I am generating 2000 bandit-plays and let different agents play 2000 bandits for 1000 steps (as described in the PDF) and then average the reward as well as the percentage of optimal actions.

**In the PDF**, the result looks like this:

[image]

However, I am not able to reproduce this. If I am using simple averaging, all the agents with exploration (`epsilon > 0`) actually play worse than an agent without exploration. This is weird because the possibility of exploration should allow agents to leave the local optimum more often and reach out to better actions.

As you can see below, this is not the case for my implementation. Also note that I have added agents which use weighted-averaging. These work but even in that case, raising `epsilon` results in a degradation of the agents performance.

[image]

Any ideas what's wrong in my code?

#### The code (MVP)

```
from abc import ABC
from typing import List

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from multiprocessing.pool import Pool


class Strategy(ABC):

    def update_estimates(self, step: int, estimates: np.ndarray, action: int, reward: float):
        raise NotImplementedError()


class Averaging(Strategy):

    def __str__(self):
        return 'avg'

    def update_estimates(self, step: int, estimates: np.ndarray, action: int, reward: float):
        current = estimates[action]
        return current + 1.0 / step * (reward - current)


class WeightedAveraging(Strategy):

    def __init__(self, alpha):
        self.alpha = alpha

    def __str__(self):
        return 'weighted-avg_alpha=%.2f' % self.alpha

    def update_estimates(self, step: int, estimates: List[float], action: int, reward: float):
        current = estimates[action]
        return current + self.alpha * (reward - current)


class Agent:

    def __init__(self, nb_actions, epsilon, strategy: Strategy):
        self.nb_actions = nb_actions
        self.epsilon = epsilon
        self.estimates = np.zeros(self.nb_actions)
        self.strategy = strategy

    def __str__(self):
        return ','.join(['eps=%.2f' % self.epsilon, str(self.strategy)])

    def get_action(self):
        best_known = np.argmax(self.estimates)
        if np.random.rand() < self.epsilon and len(self.estimates) > 1:
            explore = best_known
            while explore == best_known:
                explore = np.random.randint(0, len(self.estimates))
            return explore
        return best_known

    def update_estimates(self, step, action, reward):
        self.estimates[action] = self.strategy.update_estimates(step, self.estimates, action, reward)

    def reset(self):
        self.estimates = np.zeros(self.nb_actions)


def play_bandit(agent, nb_arms, nb_steps):

    agent.reset()

    bandit_rewards = np.random.normal(0, 1, nb_arms)

    rewards = list()
    optimal_actions = list()

    for step in range(1, nb_steps + 1):

        action = agent.get_action()
        reward = bandit_rewards[action] + np.random.normal(0, 1)
        agent.update_estimates(step, action, reward)

        rewards.append(reward)
        optimal_actions.append(np.argmax(bandit_rewards) == action)

    return pd.DataFrame(dict(
        optimal_actions=optimal_actions,
        rewards=rewards
    ))


def main():
    nb_tasks = 2000
    nb_steps = 1000
    nb_arms = 10

    fig, (ax_rewards, ax_optimal) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex='col', figsize=(8, 9))

    pool = Pool()

    agents = [
        Agent(nb_actions=nb_arms, epsilon=0.00, strategy=Averaging()),
        Agent(nb_actions=nb_arms, epsilon=0.01, strategy=Averaging()),
        Agent(nb_actions=nb_arms, epsilon=0.10, strategy=Averaging()),
        Agent(nb_actions=nb_arms, epsilon=0.00, strategy=WeightedAveraging(0.5)),
        Agent(nb_actions=nb_arms, epsilon=0.01, strategy=WeightedAveraging(0.5)),
        Agent(nb_actions=nb_arms, epsilon=0.10, strategy=WeightedAveraging(0.5)),
    ]

    for agent in agents:

        print('Agent: %s' % str(agent))

        args = [(agent, nb_arms, nb_steps) for _ in range(nb_tasks)]
        results = pool.starmap(play_bandit, args)

        df_result = sum(results) / nb_tasks
        df_result.rewards.plot(ax=ax_rewards, label=str(agent))
        df_result.optimal_actions.plot(ax=ax_optimal)

    ax_rewards.set_title('Rewards')
    ax_rewards.set_ylabel('Average reward')
    ax_rewards.legend()
    ax_optimal.set_title('Optimal action')
    ax_optimal.set_ylabel('% optimal action')
    ax_optimal.set_xlabel('steps')
    plt.xlim([0, nb_steps])
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I think your Q value calculation is wrong. You need to sum all rewards over the number you selected this specific action. I don't see that you keeping track on action selection or I am wrong? Should be sum(rewards)/N(action)

Comment: @PySeeker My mistake was that I didn't divided by `N(action)` but by `step` (the current overall step) which is wrong. a_guest pointed that out in his answer. The sum of rewards is implicit. I think you mean [Equation 2.3 on page 37](https://web.stanford.edu/class/psych209/Readings/SuttonBartoIPRLBook2ndEd.pdf)?

Comment: Yes I mean the same. N(action) is the number the action was taken. Which should be in the place of step.

Comment: @PySeeker Alright, thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the formula for the update rule

```
new_estimate = current_estimate + 1.0 / step * (reward - current_estimate)
```

the parameter `step` should be the number of times that the particular `action` has been taken, not the overall step number of the simulation. So you need to store that variable alongside the action values in order to use it for the update.

This can also be seen from the pseudo-code box at the end of chapter 2.4 Incremental Implementation:

[image: Screenshot]

<sup>*(source: Richard S. Sutton and Andrew G. Barto: Reinforcement Learning - An Introduction, second edition, 2018, Chapter 2.4 Incremental Implementation)*</sup>

Comment: Ah, yes indeed. It's actually also in Eq. 2.1 but I completely overlooked that fact. Now the plots look more like as if the agent is learning something. It's still not the same as in the book but your answer is definitely correct.